# La sección "Resaltado de sintaxis para código" no existe en la ayuda de formato de Meta

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

Me acabo de dar cuenta que en la [ayuda de edición de Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) falta una sección que sí está en la [ayuda de edición del sitio principal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help):

En el sitio principal:

> [image]

En Meta:

> [image]

Pensé que sería porque en Meta puede no ser necesaria esta funcionalidad, pero luego me di cuenta que en Meta Stack Overflow sí lo tienen ([enlace](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)).

Luego podemos traducir el enlace [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) y así tener la referencia en castellano :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es que faltara la ayuda, es que la característica estaba deshabilitada (no se realizaba resaltado de código). Tampoco estaba habilitada en el sitio meta en portugués, pero sí en los sitios en ruso y japonés (además del sitio principal como se apunta en la pregunta), lo cual achaco a un simple despiste. Lo he habilitado en ambos sitios.