# ¿Por qué Meta Stack Overflow tiene una opción para agregar código?

Tags: soporte, meta, stack-snippets

Estuve viendo algo interesante, o raro para mí, porque Meta Stack Overflow cuenta en su editor de preguntas con una opción para agregar código (HTML, CSS, JavaScript), e igual tiene la opción `<pre>`. ¿Por qué?

Si Meta, hasta donde conozco, es para hacer preguntas relacionadas a Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cada sitio (principal y Meta por separado) pueden habilitar o deshabilitar stack snippets. En Meta, solicitamos que se habilitara hace un tiempo (el 24/2/17 se [habilitó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1462/127) el resaltado).

Estos son algunos casos de uso, entre otros, que se pueden dar en los que se muestre código:

- Reportar un [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) con código que lo reproduzca.
- Una pregunta acerca de si está bien preguntar algo en Stack Overflow en español, o cómo se podría modificar la pregunta para que sea aceptable (con la etiqueta [revisión-de-pregunta](/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-pregunta)).
- Una prueba en [Pruebas de formato (Sandbox)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1706/127) para ver cómo quedaría el código.

---

La sintaxis con `<pre>` se puede utilizar tanto en el sitio principal como en Meta, y es una alternativa más para publicar en formato de código, además del botón <kbd>`{ }`</kbd> (o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>). En este caso, también se puede dar para:

- Una pregunta acerca de una consulta en [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) (etiqueta [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer)) que esté referida a una métrica del sitio, donde no se trate de la sintaxis de SQL, sino de los resultados obtenidos, y su significado para la comunidad.

Comment: ¡Hey! Me ganaste por 8 segundos y ambos incluimos "Pruebas de formato", jeje

Answer (score 2):

La razón por la cual se puede agregar código aquí es porque el sitio principal es un sitio para programadores y a los programadores les gusta escribir código. A algunos les gusta tanto que ante la menor provocación lo escriben.

Por ejemplo, está [Pruebas de formato (Sandbox)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1706/65)

Cabe aclarar que Meta Stack Overflow en español no es exclusivamente para preguntas sobre Stack Exchange, de hecho, en primera instancia es para preguntas sobre el funcionamiento del sitio principal, sus políticas, reportar bugs,  su comunidad. Las preguntas sobre Stack Exchange en primera instancia deberían tratarse en Meta Stack Exchange, pero quienes prefieran hacerlo en español, pueden hacerlo aquí, con las correspondientes salvedades.